Converting copper (II) oxide to copper with ethanol?
Anyone know if it possible to covert $\ce{CuO}$ to $\ce{Cu}$ using ethanol? I was thinking that the stoichiometry would be something like this:
$$\ce{6CuO (s) + CH3CH2OH ⟶ 6Cu (s) + 2CO2 + 3H2O}$$
but I couldn't find any place online that mentioned the reaction, and what's the best catalyst (I would imagine heating the ethanol to a gaseous phase, but it would be nice to confirm before trying anything myself).

Compare https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/151327/how-does-copper-oxidise-alcohols - is this appreciably different?

The copper oxide itself is an effective catalyst. A standard demonstration is placing a hot copper wire (covered by surface oxide) in methanol, ethanol or other alcohol vapor, which is reduced to formaldehyde. The reaction proceeds so rapidly that it keeps the wire hot enough to glow!
BTW, do not try this reaction without proper fire safety! Flames can not only come from the reaction vessel, but can flash back to an open container!

Thanks for the answer! So the reaction creates formaldehyde? So that's not really great news
